# How does the definition of a limit prove itself if the values (super) close to the value suddenly changes?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, proof-verification

So I wondering how the definition of a limit is proved if suddenly when $x \rightarrow a$ the value suddenly changes.

Consider the function and its limit as $x \rightarrow 0$:

$\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 0}} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+9}-3}{x^2}$

In this example, values "close" to $1$ seem to tend towards $0$, however, "more closer" the values suddenly change and the limit is not defined. So how does the definition of a limit prove itself, how close is close?

Close-up:

[image: Function close-up]

Closer-up:
[image: Function closer-up]

Thanks.

Comment: As x goes to 0 or 1? You have written both

Comment: @TomGrubb $0$. It's edited.

Comment: @littleO No, I do mean it to be $x^2$.

Comment: @Strikers I suspect that the values "suddenly changing" is a result of numerical error.

Comment: @TheoBendit Hi, what do you mean by numerical error?

Comment: That second graph is definitely a result of numerical error. Roughly, your computer is calculating intermediate values and rounding them off to a finite number of significant figures. So when you subtract two numbers that are very close to each other and then divide by a very small number, you get a dramatic increase in the error in the computed value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "closer-up" graph is simply wrong.  The values do not change in the way shown on the graph, and instead continue to smoothly approach $1/6$ like in your "close-up" graph.

The strange behavior of the "closer-up" graph is presumably a result of the program being used to draw the graph not being able to calculate intermediate steps with enough precision in order to get a good approximation to $\frac{\sqrt{x^2+9}-3}{x^2}$ when $x$ is extremely small.  In particular, I would guess that small rounding errors in the computation of $\sqrt{x^2+9} - 3$ (which is a number little more than $0$) are getting magnified enormously because they are being multiplied by the very large number $\frac{1}{x^2}$ (i.e. $(\sqrt{x^2+9} - 3) \cdot \frac{1}{x^2}$, which is supposed to be close to $\frac{1}{6}$)

In any case, to rigorously prove that the limit has a certain value, it does not suffice to zoom in on the graph to *any* level of precision.  Instead you must *prove* that the limit definition is satisfied, so that for *all* $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ with the required property.  This $\delta$ could be arbitrarily small, possibly too small to show up on whatever graph you draw (i.e., you need to zoom in more to see that the function stays within $\epsilon$ of the limit).

Comment: Hi, I think you mean by a very _small_ number. Also, what do you mean by $\epsilon>0$? Thanks.

Comment: @Strikers: If $x$ is very small, then $1/x^2$ is very large.  Here I am using $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ as they appear in the usual definition of a limit (for instance, as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Functions_of_a_single_variable).

Comment: Okay, so then I think you mean they are being _divided_ by a really large number.

Comment: Or, you forgot to add $-3$ to $\sqrt{x^2+9}$ then say it is being multiplied by a very large number, $\frac{1}{x^2}$. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing strange happening at any point close to $x=0$. The function is perfectly well defined, continuous and approaches the same value from both sides. It looks like this:
[image]

Where the point exactly at $x=0$ is undefined. But the limit exists and it's $1/6$ as @littleO shows. The value never "suddenly changes", and the limit is well defined. Here's a nice article that might help: http://www.mathwarehouse.com/calculus/limits/how-to-determine-when-limits-do-not-exist.php

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reponse. However, I suggest taking a much closer look and seeing the behavior. Thanks.

Comment: Please do explain, do you disagree with anything I've said or do you want more information?

Comment: Hi, yes I disagree, please see my edited post for the images. Thanks.

Comment: That is not the true nature of the behavior, as @Theo Bendit suggests, the wild behavior you observe is due to rounding errors in the computer. If you recast your equation as $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+9}+3}$$ you should see the "erratic behavior" disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment, but here's how I would evaluate this limit:
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 9} - 3}{x^2} &=
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(\sqrt{x^2 + 9} - 3)(\sqrt{x^2 + 9} + 3)}{x^2(\sqrt{x^2+9} + 3)} \\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2 + 9 - 9}{x^2 (\sqrt{x^2 + 9} + 3)} \\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + 9} + 3} \\
&= \frac16. 
\end{align}

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reponse. However, I suggest taking a much closer look and seeing the behavior. Thanks.

Comment: @Strikers I think that what you are observing is just roundoff error. Computers don't have unlimited precision when they do arithmetic.

Comment: Hi, what exactly do you mean by that? Thanks.

Comment: The $\sqrt{x}$ function is irrational at most values of $x$ so to get an exact value for $\sqrt{x^2+9}$ would require infinite memory to store. The computer can't do that so it rounds to the nearest 15 decimal places or so (estimate). But when $x^2$ is very small then $\mbox{something}/x^2$ becomes very large and the way the computer rounded the numerator becomes increasingly important. Those rounding errors, amplified by dividing by a tiny number, are causing the wild behavior you see in the graph. But it's not the true behavior, it's just errors internal to the computer.

Comment: @bRost03 Okay, that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: We experience catastrophic cancellation when computing $\sqrt{x^2 +9} -3$ (subtracting two nearly equal numbers), then dividing by a small number makes the loss of precision even worse.

Comment: @littleO Okay that's good. Thanks.

Comment: @brost03 Oh yes, thanks.